# Rails 6 & Materialize: Select multiples close after selecting one value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm trying to create a dynamic select multiple that allows an "Admin" to select some users.  It works totally fine, but every time I select a value, it closes out of the dropdown.  Here's the relevant code:

Here's the javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, {constrainWidth: false});
});
```

Here's the form's code:

```
<div class = "xtrapadding">
    <%=f.label "Select Intern(s)"%>
    <%= f.collection_select(:user_ids, User.all, :id, (:fullname) , {class: "stopDrop"}, {:multiple => true})%>
</div>
```

I tried adding that class "stopDrop" with the following code, but could never get it to fire:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('.stopDrop').on("click", function() {
     console.log("Test")
     alert("test");
     event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help you can give! This is something I've been beating my head on for a few hours.

Comment: I tried copy and pasting materialize's exact example to see if that would work.  It didn't, even their example closes after selecting one.

Comment: Have tried a few other things like playing with options, still no luck.  Would still appreciate any help.